# A simple paradox of True or False

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, paradox, truth, language

In a piece of paper, it was written:

> The statement written in the paper is false.

Is that statement actually true or false?

Comment: There is no duplicity: the issue here is about solutions in general, not only involving formal logic, but in formal languages​​, semantics, etc.

Comment: I can see an argument for this not being a duplicate, but then such a formulation borders being non-constructive. I'm inclined to let the community decide at this point.

Comment: It's false! No, it's true! No, it's false! No, it's … "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" inside your head :) Seriously, as it stands the question is non-constructive. Vote to close. Could @sidarth explain what kind of answers he expects? E.g. solutions where the statement has a definite truth value (like Prior's)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the solution of [Tarski:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox)

> Alfred Tarski diagnosed the paradox as arising only in languages that
>   are "semantically closed", by which he meant a language in which it is
>   possible for one sentence to predicate truth (or falsehood) of another
>   sentence in the same language (or even of itself). To avoid
>   self-contradiction, it is necessary when discussing truth values to
>   envision levels of languages, each of which can predicate truth (or
>   falsehood) only of languages at a lower level. So, when one sentence
>   refers to the truth-value of another, it is semantically higher. The
>   sentence referred to is part of the "object language", while the
>   referring sentence is considered to be a part of a "meta-language"
>   with respect to the object language. It is legitimate for sentences in
>   "languages" higher on the semantic hierarchy to refer to sentences
>   lower in the "language" hierarchy, but not the other way around. This
>   prevents a system from becoming self-referential.

And [Prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) too:

> Arthur Prior asserts that there is nothing paradoxical about the liar
>   paradox. His claim (which he attributes to Charles Sanders Peirce and
>   John Buridan) is that every statement includes an implicit assertion
>   of its own truth. Thus, for example, the statement, "It is true that
>   two plus two equals four", contains no more information than the
>   statement "two plus two equals four", because the phrase "it is true
>   that..." is always implicitly there. And in the self-referential
>   spirit of the Liar Paradox, the phrase "it is true that..." is
>   equivalent to "this whole statement is true and ...". Thus the
>   following two statements are equivalent:
>
> This statement is false. 
>   This statement is true and this statement is false.
>
> The latter is a simple
>   contradiction of the form "A and not A", and hence is false. There is
>   therefore no paradox because the claim that this two-conjunct Liar is
>   false does not lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Tarskis idea sounds similar to truth stratification in Russells theory of types - except that was motivated by his own paradox.